# パッケージ javax.sql は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: <unnamed>, java.sqlの回避方法について

Tags: java, eclipse, java8

JDKをJDK8 → JDK11に変更してビルドした際に以下のエラーが発生しました。
このエラーの回避方法が分からないのですが、
ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけますでしょうか。

エラー
パッケージ javax.sql は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.sql

環境
・Windows 10
・Oracle OpenJDK11
・Eclipse2020

(補足)
1)現在分かっていることは、
　Javaのビルドパスに「j2ee.jar」を追加すると上記エラーが発生します。
　Javaのビルドパスから「j2ee.jar」を削除すると上記エラーは消えますが、
　「j2ee.jar」を使用しているプログラムの箇所でエラー(class not found)が発生します。

2)Eclipseから以下の操作を実施しましたが、エラーは解消されません。
　該当プロジェクトを右クリック→プロパティ→Javaのビルド・パス→ライブラリータブ→
　クラスパスの方に該当プロジェクトで使用するjarファイルを設定する。
　(JREシステム・ライブラリーはモジュールパスにあります。)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`javax.sql` がクラスパス、モジュールパスの両方に含まれているのが原因だと思われます。
今回の場合、JDK, `jee.jar`の双方に含まれているのでしょう。

例えば次のような対処が考えられます。

- `jee.jar` から `javax/sql` を取り除く
- `jee.jar`の代わりに、より新しいものを利用する。

  - `jee.jar`が何者なのか分かりませんが、例えば[`javax:javaee-api`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:javax%20AND%20a:javaee-api)で代替可能であれば、いずれのバージョンにも `javax/sql` は含まれていないようです。

参考:

- [Eclipse is confused by imports (“accessible from more than one module”)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572922/4506703)

   - Stack Overflow